# python3 recursion animation

Tags: recursion, dictionary, python-3.x, quickdraw

[image]

I need to animate a similar animation in quickdraw and I'm told to use recursion. I'm having a hard time with the orbits and this is the code I have for orbiting circle but I have no idea how to use recursion to create the above image.

```
import math


print("circle",400,300,50)

print("flush false")

centreX=400
centreY=300
radius=100
angle=math.pi/2



while True:
    print("color 0 0 0")
    print("clear")
    print("color 255 0 255")
    print("circle",centreX,centreY,radius)
    childX=math.sin(angle)*radius*1.5+centreX
    childY=math.cos(angle)*radius*1.5+centreY
    print("circle",childX,childY,radius/2)
    print("refresh")
    angle+=0.01
```

the data file looks like this:

```
RootObject: Sun

Object: Sun
Satellites: Mercury,Venus,Earth,Mars,Jupiter,Saturn,Uranus,Neptune,Ceres,Pluto,Haumea,Makemake,Eris
Radius: 20890260
Orbital Radius: 0

Object: Miranda
Orbital Radius: 5822550
Radius: 23500
Period: 1.413

Object: Ariel
Orbital Radius: 8595000
Radius: 60000
Period: 2.520379

Object: Umbriel
Orbital Radius: 11983500
Radius: 60000
Period: 4.144177

Object: Titania
Orbital Radius: 19575000
Radius: 75000
Period: 8.7058

Object: Oberon
Orbital Radius: 26235000
Radius: 75000
Period: 13.463

Object: Uranus
Orbital Radius: 453572956
Radius: 2555900
Period: 30799
Satellites: Puck,Miranda,Ariel,Umbriel,Titania,Oberon

Object: Neptune
Orbital Radius: 550000000
Radius: 2476400
Period: 60190
Satellites: Triton

Object: Triton
Orbital Radius: 40000000
Radius: 135300
Period: -5.8

Object: Mercury
Orbital Radius: 38001200
Period: 87.9691
Radius: 243900.7

Object: Venus
Orbital Radius: 57477000
Period: 224.698
Radius: 605100.8

Object: Earth
Orbital Radius: 77098290
Period: 365.256363004
Radius: 637100.0
Satellites: Moon

Object: Moon
Orbital Radius: 18128500
Radius: 173700.10
Period: 27.321582

Object: Mars
Orbital Radius: 106669000
Period: 686.971
Radius: 339600.2
Satellites: Phobos,Deimos

Object: Phobos
Orbital Radius: 3623500.6
Radius: 200000
Period: 0.31891023

Object: Deimos
Orbital Radius: 8346000
Period: 1.26244
Radius: 200000.2

Object: Jupiter
Orbital Radius: 210573600
Period: 4332.59
Radius: 7149200
Satellites: Io,Europa,Ganymede,Callisto

Object: Ceres
Orbital Radius: 130995855
Period: 1679.67
Radius: 48700

Object: Io
Orbital Radius: 22000000
Period: 1.7691377186
Radius: 182100.3

Object: Europa
Orbital Radius: 36486200
Period: 3.551181
Radius: 156000.8

Object: Ganymede
Orbital Radius: 47160000
Period: 7.15455296
Radius: 263400

Object: Callisto
Orbital Radius: 69700000
Period: 16.6890184
Radius: 241000

Object: Saturn
Orbital Radius: 353572956
Period: 10759.22
Radius: 6026800
Satellites: Mimas,Enceladus,Tethys,Dione,Rhea,Titan,Iapetus

Object: Mimas
Orbital Radius: 8433396
Radius: 20600
Period: 0.9

Object: Enceladus
Orbital Radius: 10706000
Radius: 25000
Period: 1.4

Object: Tethys
Orbital Radius: 13706000
Radius: 50000
Period: 1.9

Object: Dione
Orbital Radius: 17106000
Radius: 56000
Period: 2.7

Object: Rhea
Orbital Radius: 24000000
Radius: 75000
Period: 4.5

Object: Titan
Orbital Radius: 50706000
Radius: 257600
Period: 15.945

Object: Iapetus
Radius: 75000
Orbital Radius: 72285891
Period: 79
```

I'm supposed to import the data into a recursive function to create the orbits and the animation but I have no idea how. I've tried almost everything, Its very frustrating.

Would this code work?

```
print("flush false")
scale=250/max([dict[x]["Orbital Radius"] for x in dict if "Orbital Radius" in dict[x]])
t=0
x=400
y=300
while True:
    print("refresh")
    print("colour 0 0 0")
    print("clear")
    print("colour 255 255 255")
    print("fillcircle",x,y,dict['Sun']['Radius']*scale)
    print("text ", "\"Sun\"",x+dict['Sun']['Radius']*scale,y)
    r_earth=dict['Earth']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
    print("circle",x,y,r_earth)
    r_X=x+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/dict['Earth']['Period'])*r_earth
    r_Y=y+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/dict['Earth']['Period'])*r_earth
    print("fillcircle",r_X,r_Y,dict['Earth']['Radius']*scale)
    print("text ", "\"Earth\"",r_X+dict['Earth']['Radius']*scale,r_Y)
    t+=0.02
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [python3 recursion animation in QuickDraw](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520435/python3-recursion-animation-in-quickdraw)

Comment: its pretty close. I'm just severly frustrated at not being able to solve it.